# Using leaflet with large data - ACS data for all counties in U.S

Tags: r, leaflet, census, leaflet-r

I'm plotting ACS data (counts of low-income children) for each county across the entire U.S.  I don't have any markers, just a county shapefile and a value for each county in a popup.

Unsurprisingly this is too large for browsers to handle.  I've seen some similar questions here that deal with clustering, but since I have nothing to cluster I'm starting a new question.

I've tried breaking it up into 4 regional maps, but even those are too much.

Is there some way to lower the footprint, but still have all the county specific data?

I'm using R to generate the map, so R-specific responses are helpful but not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is found in r package `rmapshaper`.

Apply the function `rmapshaper::ms_simplify()` to the result of `tigris::geo_join()` (the merged Large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame that is the combination of shapefile and data for each geography).

For my initial merge file that was 685 MB, the result was 17.6 MB. Voila!